# Why Mails sent with django and mailgun (smtp) to my gmail account don't show up in my gmail inbox yet it gets sent successfully?

Tags: python, django, gmail, mailgun, django-mailgun

I am sending emails using mailgun (smtp) to my Gmail account don't show up in my Gmail inbox yet it gets sent successfully.

- **I am using django web development framework.**
- **I am using mailgun (smtp).**
- **I am still using the sandbox testing environment**

Comment: If they are sent out, it's not a programming issue. What happen between mailing and Gmail is out of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would change from the sandbox to a (your) real domain.
This detailed description may help you: [Can I send email with mailgun sandbox domain under my local OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150905/can-i-send-email-with-mailgun-sandbox-domain-under-my-local-os/68542876#68542876)